# Lactobacillales vs LAB (Lactic acid bacteria)

Tags: bacteriology, taxonomy

As far as I understand bacteria of order *Lactobacillales* are all LAB (Lactic acid bacteria). So often "*Lactobacillales*" and "LAB" are used interchangeably.

But I also thought that this is not the whole truth, because there are LAB which are not of order *Lactobacillales*.

Can anyone elaborate on this topic and is there a paper/review explaining the consensus on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lactic acid fermentation is the most common type of fermentation among Eubacteria, and it's found on several genera.

Actually, regarding the fermentation types, we can say as a general rule:

- Ethanol fermentation: found in Plants and Fungi.
- Lactic acid fermentation: found in Bacteria and Animals.

That being said, according to the *Todar's Online Textbook of Bacteriology*,

> Although many genera of bacteria produce lactic acid as a primary or secondary end-product of fermentation, the term Lactic Acid Bacteria is conventionally reserved for genera in the Order Lactobacillales.

And according to *Lactic Acid Bacteria: Microbiological and Functional Aspects, Fourth Edition*:

> They [LAB] belong to the Phylum Firmicutes, Class Bacilli and Order Lactobacillales.

These genera are: *Lactobacillus*, *Leuconostoc*, *Pediococcus*, *Lactococcus*, *Streptococcus*, *Carnobacterium*, *Enterococcus*, *Oenococcus*, *Tetragenococcus*, *Vagococcus* and *Weisella*.

The problem here is that not all lactic acid producing bacteria are called a LAB. Therefore, Lactobacillales and LAB **can** be used interchangeably. However, you cannot say that all bacteria that perform lactic acid fermentation are LAB.

Sources:

- [Textbookofbacteriology.net. (2017). Online Textbook of Bacteriology. [online] Available at: http://textbookofbacteriology.net/index.html [Accessed 3 May 2017].](http://textbookofbacteriology.net/lactics.html)
- [Lactic Acid Bacteria: Microbiological and Functional Aspects, Fourth Edition](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=tFjsAuo5WocC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lactic%20acid%20bacteria&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=families&f=false)
- [En.wikipedia.org. (2017). Lactobacillales. [online] Available at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactobacillales [Accessed 3 May 2017].](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactobacillales)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I found this sources already. Is there any review/paper confirming this as the consensus among taxonomists?

Comment: Have a look at this book, page 2: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=tFjsAuo5WocC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lactic+acid+bacteria&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=families&f=false